# How to balance load for web crawling

Tags: mysql, algorithm, web-scraping, architecture, web-crawler

Assume the following scenario - 
I have 1000 distinct IP addresses and 50 urls (webpages). I need to crawl these webpages with certain constraints in mind -

1. Every single url must be visited by 500 different ip addresses. (i.e. 500 visits for every url)
2. An ip address should visit a url only once. eg: `1.1.1.1` cannot be used to hit url `http://example.com` more than once
3. The load amongst the ips should be balanced as much as possible, throughout the crawling. `1.1.1.1` shouldn't have crawled 100 times while some other ip has only done 4-5 crawls, as this isn't balanced

I'm currently logging every crawl entry in Mysql table. So if `1.1.1.1` has visited `http://example.com` and `http://test.com`, there would be 2 entries in the table

`(1.1.1.1, http://example.com)` and `(1.1.1.1, http://test.com)`

My loadbalancing strategey is this - 
*Before every crawl, find the ip with the least crawls done so far and use that*.

However, i feel this isn't very optimized as i'd have to perform a grouping query to get the count and then sort them, everytime before i do a crawling.

What would be some better ways of handling this?

**PS**: To speed up the crawling, I'm using multiple threads too

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using a list of the IP addresses and give that to [itertools.cycle()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle). Then you simply give each URL to the next 500 IP addresses you get from [itertools.cycle()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

one way to multithread this would be to take the output from cycle and push that to a blocking queue from one thread. Then you can have other threads that each take a URL and distribute to the next 500 IPs you get from the queue.

Comment: I forgot to mention there can be duplicate URL entries. Since every IP can visit a URL only once, there has to be some additional checks also involved right?

Comment: That complicates the whole thing but isn&#39;t impossible. If each worker keeps track of which urls it has visited, then it could return "already visited" and have the distributer try again.

Comment: Indeed, but a worst-case scenario could be the distributer goes through N-1 iterations to figure out the valid IP, if all other N-1 ips have already visited it. I was wondering if there were probably smarter ways of handling it

Comment: Indeed, but going through that worst case would still be quite fast, hardly any time or computation at all.